# how to get session changes using windows service

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, service

I want to develop a c++ service to get notified whenever user does login or logoff the system. I went through some functions but those are asking for windows handle. Since it is a service, which windows API will be useful for this?

Comment: RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx + SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE requires no hwnd

Comment: yes, it works. thanks.